# Is it possible to access `WriterT`'s partially collected `tell`s in case of exception?

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to have a WriterT monad that is able to share its partially collected `tell`s in case of an exception? If I `try` outside of `runWriterT` the `w` seems to be discarded. If I try to `try` inside, I seem to need `MonadUnliftIO`. `MonadUnliftIO` sounds like it could help me, but that package says that it is only able to unlift monadic contexts and not monadic state which I guess Writer is. Has anyone done this with Writer or something similar?

Example pseudocode:

```hs
x <- runWriterT $ do
  result <- try $ do
    tell "a"
    tell "b"
    error "c"
    tell "d"
  case result of
    Left e -> Just e
    Right a -> Nothing

x `shouldBe` (Just "c", "ab")
```

Comment: Try to put an exception transformer "above" the writer transformer: `ExceptT e (WriterT w m) a`, and you would need to run the exception before the writer: `runWriterT (runExceptT ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code uses `error`. Morally speaking, all bets are off with `error`, because it signifies a bug in your program more than anything else. The fact that `IO` can catch the exceptions produced by it is really just an interesting quirk. Therefore, if you need this behavior, it's really best to use a proper exception monad transformer, like @Li-yaoXia recommends.

```
-- see Control.Monad.Except
action :: (MonadExcept String m, MonadWriter String m) =>
          m ()
action = do tell "a"
            tell "b"
            throwError "c"
            tell "d"

-- run action and massage it into your format
yourOutput :: (Maybe String, String)
yourOutput = runWriter $ fmap (either Just (const Nothing)) $ runExceptT actions
```

As to why `error` can't really work (at least, in a nice way), consider what `error _ :: WriterT w m a` actually means. `error _ :: Int` means "there is supposed to be a number here, but instead there's just a mistake." `WriterT w m a` is a type of program; the type of programs that keep of a log of type `w`, do some other stuff (`m`), and return `a`. Therefore, `error _ :: WriterT w m a` does not mean "a program that throws a recoverable error, preserving the log of type `w`," it means "there is supposed to be a program here, but instead there's just a mistake." Metaphorically speaking, the `action` psuedo-code you posted abruptly *runs out of program*, even though the type didn't mention that your program was allowed to suddenly terminate, and you should (metaphorically) thank your lucky stars that you are allowed to set up a replacement program (with `try`) rather than being properly chastised for the error!

With the ivory-towertop preaching out of the way, let's assume that we really do have

```
action :: MonadWriter String m => m ()
action = do tell "a"
            tell "b"
            error "c"
            tell "d"
```

and we just have to deal with it. Assuming you use the lazy version of `Writer`, you'll be happy to note that

```
runWriter action =
  ( ()
  , "a" ++ "b" ++ (case error "c" of (_, c) -> c) ++ "d"
  )
```

There exists this function that "salvages" a list by catching an impure exception (the immoral, "there is literally no program" kind I said `error` was) if it occurs while evaluating the spine.

```
-- can be recast as Free (a,) () -> IO (Free (a,) (Maybe e))
-- essentially, that type encodes the intuition that a list may end in [] (nil)
-- or in an error
salvageList :: Exception e => [a] -> IO ([a], Maybe e)
salvageList xs = catch (do xs' <- evaluate xs
                           case xs' of
                                [] -> return ([], Nothing)
                                (x : tl) -> do (tl', e) <- salvageList tl
                                               return (x : tl', e)
                       ) (\e -> return ([], Just e))
```

Which works:

```
-- we get the return value, too! that makes me feel... surprisingly weirded out!
yourOutputPlus :: IO ((), Maybe String, String)
yourOutputPlus = do let (val, log) = runWriter action
                    (realLog, error) <- salvageList log
                    return (val, fmap (\(ErrorCall msg) -> msg) error, realLog)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want state to survive a runtime exception like this, your best bet is to use mutable variables. This is the approach we use inside Yesod, for example. The `rio` library has a `MonadWriter` instance based on mutable references that works this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-13.17 script
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
import Test.Hspec
import RIO
import RIO.Writer

main = hspec $ it "writer and exceptions" $ do
  ref <- newSomeRef ""
  result <- tryAny $ runRIO ref $ do
    tell "a"
    tell "b"
    error "c"
    tell "d"
  case result of
    Left _ -> pure ()
    Right () -> error "it should have failed!!!"

  written <- readSomeRef ref
  written `shouldBe` "ab"
```

I touch on this (and related points) in my talk "Everything you didn't want to know about monad transformer state":

- Slides: https://www.snoyman.com/reveal/monad-transformer-state
- Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZIN9f9rI34